# Try Catch on executable exe in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I want to do a Try Catch on an .exe in Powershell, what I have looks like this:

```
Try
{
    $output = C:\psftp.exe ftp.blah.com 2>&1
}
Catch
{
    echo "ERROR: "
    echo $output
    return
}

echo "DONE: "
echo $output
```

When I use say an invalid domain, it returns an error like `psftp.exe : Fatal: Network error: Connection refused` but my code is not catching that.

How would I catch errors?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`try / catch` in PowerShell doesn't work with native executables. After you make the call to psftp.exe, check the automatic variable `$LastExitCode`.  That will contain psftp's exit code e.g.:

```
$output = C:\psftp.exe ftp.blah.com 2>&1
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
{
    echo "ERROR: "
    echo $output
    return
}
```

The script above presumes that the exe returns 0 on success and non-zero otherwise.  If that is not the case, adjust the `if (...)` condition accordingly.

Comment: I must say that in my case I have an executable that, for test proposes, I throw an exception in the beginning of the code and when my powershell script runs a popup windows appears due to the exception and I have to click on the button to continue. The point here is that the exception is not caught on the if statement neither on a try catch block.

Answer (score 10):

*> try / catch in PowerShell doesn't work with native executables.*

Actually it does, but only if you use "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'" AND append "2>&1".

See "Handling Native Commands" / Tobias Weltner at https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/ebookv2/posts/chapter-11-error-handling.

E.g.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Try
{
    $output = C:\psftp.exe ftp.blah.com 2>&1
}
Catch
{
    echo "ERROR: "
    echo $output
    return
}
echo "DONE: "
echo $output
```

Comment: It's important to note, that this method depends on the command writing to stderr, not on its exit code.

So a command that fails and returns a non-zero exit code, without writing to stderr will *not* trigger the Catch here. Similarly, a command that succeeds (returns 0 exit code) but still writes to stderr with some info (as many do), *will incorrectly* trigger the Catch.

So I'd discourage this approach in favor of the check on $LastExitCode.

Comment: Curiously, in my specific case I only achieved the expected results (exec properly writing to stderr) after I  set up $ErrorActionPreference  = 'Stop'; only then I got $LastExitCode showing -1 as it would be expected. If I didn't, either success or fail would exit with 0 nevertheless. Of course this means that this exec does have a bad error handling, which should be fixed just in case someone have access to the source code.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try{
.\app.exe 
 }

catch [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException] {
  Write-Host $_
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**